# How to prevent Vscode or Prettier from breaking code when using "<" (less-than symbol)?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier

When using `<` in VS Code, it really destroy the format of my code.

I'm not sure if this an issue for VS Code or Prettier.

[image]

As you can see, the "<" symbol is in Red color which mean invalid, right?

But when using the ">" (greater-than), it's just okay.

[image]

Comment: What templating language are you using?

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure where to find that. But I'm using, php, html and laravel.

Comment: you answered it. Look for a laravel extension for VSCode.

Comment: That'll be https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements, then. I doubt Prettier understands Blade files.

Comment: HTML only allows literal `<` inside `script` tags, so if you use a bare HTML formatter you get trouble, `<` is part of tag definition.